# Not able to send email while using logback

Tags: java, slf4j, logback

I am using logback.xml file for emailing the logging details. when i am using following jars.

```
slf4j-api-1.7.1.jar
pegasus-exe-0.0.4.jar
logback-core-1.1.1.jar
```

when i tried to run the application i am getting the following exception

```
Failed to instantiate [ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext]
Reported exception:
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that something was interface and was implemented by other class but now it became class and therefore cannot be implemented but can be only extended.

Shortly it means that you meet version incompatibility. Unfortunately you have not sent stack trace and I cannot download the pegasus right now (something does not work on their site). So, here are some recommendations I can give you on the top of my head.

First try to update slf4j to the newest version 1.7.6. 
If error remains examine stack trace to understand what kind of dependency is wrong and find compatible version.

Generally use maven or gradle and (almost) forget about version incompatibility problems.